# Is HDC and Memory DC different?

Tags: winapi

I am studying Double buffering in windows winapi.
When I draw text on HDC direct using DrawText function, it works well like under code.

```
case WM_PAINT:
hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
DrawText(hDC,"test",4,&rt,DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK);
DeleteDC(hMemDC);
ReleaseDC(hwnd,hDC);
EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
break;
```

But, I would like to want to use double buffering, so I make memory dc and bitblt function.
Under code is that,It don't works.I can show white empty screen.

```
case WM_PAINT:
hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
//GetClientRect(hwnd, &crt);
//hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, crt.right, crt.bottom);
//OldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);
DrawText(hMemDC,"test",4,&rt,DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK);
BitBlt(hDC,0,0,800,800,hMemDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
DeleteDC(hMemDC);
ReleaseDC(hwnd,hDC);
EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
break;
```

Is memory dc different original dc ?
If I use CreateCompatibleBitmap function, it work well.
What is concept am i missing ?
Is there website well-organized website?

Comment: Your question is a bit confused and the code you've shown is messy and basically meaningless. Perhaps this will help - when you create a memory DC it has a 1x1 monochrome bitmap selected into it by default. You also need to create a bitmap of desired size and select it in to use the memory DC. Please reformat your question to be more specific if you want more detailed help.

Answer (score 1):

A typical non-double-buffered drawing routine looks like this:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        RECT rcWnd;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcWnd);
        
        {
            DrawText(hdc, _T("Hello, world!"), -1,
                &rcWnd, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
        }
        
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

A typical double-buffered drawing routine looks like this:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        RECT rcWnd;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcWnd);

        {
            const int width = rcWnd.right - rcWnd.left
            const int height = rcWnd.bottom - rcWnd.top;

            // create a new DC based on the target HDC
            HDC hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            // create a bitmap that is compatible with the target DC
            HBITMAP hMemBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
            // select the new bitmap in to the DC, saving the old bitmap
            HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDCMem, hMemBmp);

            // do your drawing
            HBRUSH hBr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
            FillRect(hDCMem, &rcWnd, hBr);
            DeleteObject(hBr);
            DrawText(hDCMem, _T("Hello, world!"), -1,
                &rcWnd, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);

            // copy all the bits from our new DC over to the target DC
            BitBlt(hdc, rcWnd.left, rcWnd.top, width, height, hDCMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            // select the original bitmap the DC came with
            SelectObject(hDCMem, hOldBmp);
            // delete our bitmap
            DeleteObject(hMemBmp);
            // delete the DC
            DeleteDC(hDCMem);
        }
        
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
    // since we are drawing the entire area because we are double-buffering, there is
    // no need to erase the background. This will speed up your drawing.
    return TRUE;
```

`HDC` objects are all the same -- there is no special things that happen when you create another one in memory. I mean, they are all in memory, really. You are just creating another canvas to do your drawing on, then copying that canvas over in one shot.

Comment: It should be `HBITMAP hMemBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);`. `hDCMem` initially has monochrome bitmap, so you create monochome bitmap. `hdc` has associated compatible bitmap so it should be used as a format template.